# Thirteen Diagonals of a Nonagon

Tags: mathematics, geometry, no-computers

A regular nonagon has 27 diagonals, and these diagonals intersect in the interior of the nonagon at 126 distinct points.

[image: Nonagon with diagonals]

Show that it is possible to select 13 diagonals of a regular nonagon such that the selected diagonals have 13 points of intersection within the nonagon.

The image is provide as a reference and visual aid. The diagonals are colored according to length, but this is only for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: If there hadn't been a "no-computers" tag, I could have told you that there are exactly 8 solution down to rotations and reflections.  But the tag is there.

Comment: @FlorianF I might have already known that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image]

The easiest way to count is

> Diagonals: 3 horizontal, 3 pairs crossing in the middle, 4 that cross one of the horizontal lines

> Intersections: 3 in the middle, 5 left, 5 right